# Python How to split a string and print a one line separated by backslash

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python, and I am having some trouble splitting this string by the comma, then splitting it by the equal sign, reversing it, and print only the second value of each list within a list.

String to break up

```
text = "cn=username,ou=group1,ou=group2,dc=domain1,dc=enterprise"
```

End result

```
username/group1/group2/domain1/enterprise
```

Somethings I have tried

```
text = "cn=username,ou=group1,ou=group1,dc=domain1,dc=enterprise"
list_of_list = list(l.split('=') for l in (text.split(',')) )
print(text)
print(list_of_list)

output = ""
for i in list_of_list:
    output += i[1] + '/'
print(output)
```

The result is:

```
username/group1/group1/domain1/enterprise/
```

I would like to use ('/'.join()), but I do not know how to only get the second element of the inner list.

Answer (score 2):

```
text = "cn=username,ou=group1,ou=group2,dc=domain1,dc=enterprise"

result = [pair.split('=')[1] for pair in text.split(',')]
print('/'.join(result))
```

If you need a slash at the end, you can add it manually on the last line:

```
print('/'.join(result) + '/')
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for. I actually did not need the ending slash. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also do one simple modification in your code
in the list line i.e. `print(output)`
modify it as `print(output[:-1])`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a multiline solution:

```py
text = "cn=username,ou=group1,ou=group1,dc=domain1,dc=enterprise"
output = []

# Split on the ","
for component in text.split(","):

    # Split the "=" into key/value pairs
    key, value = component.split("=")

    # Append only the value to the output list
    output.append(value)

print("/".join(output))
```

For a one-liner:

```py
text = "cn=username,ou=group1,ou=group1,dc=domain1,dc=enterprise"

print("/".join([l.split("=")[-1] for l in text.split(",")]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [re](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiG4aWak_XpAhXDnOAKHYARCHkQFjAAegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F3%2Flibrary%2Fre.html&usg=AOvVaw3Rsq9kABRxR4gH08n-cRdW):

```
import re
text = "cn=username,ou=group1,ou=group2,dc=domain1,dc=enterprise"
print(re.sub(",.*?=","/",text[3:]))
```

Output:

```
username/group1/group2/domain1/enterprise
```